# Asynchronous not working in android

Tags: android, listview

I am following this tutorial for lazy loading listview in android.
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/

But the problem is the list is loading lazyly but images are downloaded in the sequential manner as provided. i.e smaller images are not downloaded first like that.
what is they doing wrong in this tutorial?

Comment: You should probably provide some of your own code

Comment: I followed the same code in the link. I changed only in the adapter like this
  Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             System.out.println("Running " + position);
             PbAndImage pb_and_image = new PbAndImage();
                pb_and_image.setImg(holder.image);
                pb_and_image.setPb(holder.pb);
             new DownloadImageTask().execute(pb_and_image);
            }
        };

        thread.start();
in the getView() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing could be intended behavior, if your app is targeting (and running on) API level 12 or above. If you run your code on, say, API level 9 -- if your app supports it -- do you see the same behavior occur? If not, that could very well be the issue.

Starting with API level 12, multiple concurrent `AsyncTask`s will execute sequentially by default, to reduce the chance of unexpected errors and race conditions. If you start your tasks with `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` rather than `execute()`, however, they will run in parallel and will not wait for preceding tasks to finish.

If you'd like further reading, here's [a good post by Dianne Hackborn](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M/xVPtz0Ax8ikJ) explaining the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the tutorial, as far as I can see. It starts an Asyntask on the getView() with the code:

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute(pb_and_image);
```

and that is the key that makes it asynchronous.

As result, instead of executing the code to fetch the image on the execution of the getView method (which is in the UI Thread), the expensive execution is performed in the background thread of the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and its results is delivered asynchronously. The order is not guaranteed, as the order of the getView calls for each row isn't under your control.

Comment: I tried with bigger and smaller images but still it is downloading in sequential manner. Don't know why.